# R bizdays trouble making it work

Tags: r, date, bizdays

Im tring to use the bizdays package to generate a vector with bus days between two dates.

```
fer = as.data.frame(as.Date(fer[1:938]))

#Define default calendar
bizdays.options$set(default.calendar=fer)

dt1 = as.Date(Sys.Date())
dt2 = as.Date(Sys.Date()-(365*10)) #sample 10 year window

#Create date vector
datas = bizseq(dt2, dt1)
```

i get this error: "Error in bizseq.Date(dt2, dt1) : Given date out of range."
the same behavior for any function bizdays et al.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `fer` is the holidays, you can try with:

```
bizdays.options$set(default.calendar=Calendar(holidays=fer))
```

Comment: Tks HubertL, your solution worked! had to set the weekends as well:

bizdays.options$set(default.calendar=Calendar(holidays=fer, weekdays=c("saturday", "sunday")))

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem, but could not apply the accepted answer to my case. What worked for me was to make sure that the first and last holiday in the vector `holidays` at least covers (or exceeds) the range of dates provided to `bizdays()`:

```
   library(bizdays)
```

This works (`from_date` and `to_date` both lie within the first and last holiday provided by `holidays`):

```
   holidays <- c("2016-08-10", "2016-08-13")

    from_date <- "2016-08-11"
    to_date <- "2016-08-12"

    cal <- Calendar(holidays, weekdays=c('sunday', 'saturday'))
    bizdays(from_date, to_date, cal)

    #1
```

This does not work (`to_date` lies outside of the last holiday of `holidays`):

```
    holidays <- c("2016-08-10", "2016-08-11")

    from_date <- "2016-08-11"
    to_date <- "2016-08-12"

    cal <- Calendar(holidays, weekdays=c('sunday', 'saturday'))
    bizdays(from_date, to_date, cal)

   # Error in bizdays.Date(from, to, cal) : Given date out of range.
```